# Is there a way to repeat a loop cycle?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to repeat a loop cycle like in code example below, without `i` incrementing by 1?

```
bool twice = true;
bool* repeated = new bool[64];
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    counter++;
    if (twice && !repeated[i])
    {
       repeated[i] = true;
       repeat;
    }
}
delete[] repeated;
cout << counter << endl;
//counter should print 128
```

Edit: All iterations need to be repeated.

Comment: decrement `i` by 1

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you allocate `repeated` dynamically? Why not just use a plain array (as in `bool repeated[64] = { false };`)? Especially since you can explicitly initialize the array, and you can't initialize the dynamically allocated memory, which leads to *undefined behavior* when you use the uninitialized data and their indeterminate values.

Comment: I mean for code to execute twice for same index.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're trying to achieve. For example, does _every_ iteration need to be repeated, or is it only some? Is it important to do one pass or are two OK? A good answer for this question, as asked, is impossible.

Comment: All iterations, edited the question.

Comment: You can easily repeat almost any portion of code if you wrap it in a function.

Comment: Wrap the code to be repeated in: 1) a function, 2) a lambda, 3) another loop, 4) or a goto, if you're bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a lambda function to wrap the interior of your loop and then simply call it twice.

```
bool twice = true;
int counter = 0;
auto execute_interior = [](const int i){/*Do something with i*/};

for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    ++counter;

    execute_interior(i);
    if (twice)
        execute_interior(i);
}

std::cout << counter << std::endl;
```

**Edit:** I moved the counter out of the lambda as it seems it should not be in the repeated part of the code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It can't be captured before it is defined. I made it an argument of the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

I asked you whether all iterations needed to be repeated and you answered in the affirmative.

I also asked whether it was important to do one pass or whether two passes would be acceptable. If it's the latter, then I will bluntly recommend that you not try to be too smart. Go with the obvious:

```
/* Count the widgets twice: */
for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j != 64; ++j)
        do_something();
}
```

If you absolutely need a single pass, then my suggestion would be just as simple, and along the lines of what @StefanKssmr already gave you and I'll add an extra comment to avoid some conscientious programmer from breaking the code down the line by removing the apparently erroneous duplication:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 64; ++i)
{
    /* This call is duplicated on purpose! */
    do_something();
    do_something();
}
```

If you need to pass the index of the iteration into `do_something` there's a bit of a dirty trick that you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 128; ++i)
    do_something(i / 2);
```

---

With all that said, I will caution you: your example likely doesn't describe the issue you're having accurately; rather it describes a very abstract implementation of a solution you've come up with and it may be that in not asking the *actual* question you have, you're getting locked into a bad design choice.

Comment: Right. I wrote the example kinda bad. I wanted the loop to repeat if there is no result (value assigned to variable or simply a `continue` inside) after the inner code in loop. That said that there can be case where all iterations need to be repeated twice and sometimes only few.